# Ionic forward view cached when side menu present

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-routing

I am building a demo application on ionic framework. My demo ionic application has three states :

```
    $stateProvider.state("app", {
        abstract : true,
        url : "/app",
        templateUrl : "app/templates/theme.html" 
    });
    $stateProvider.state("app.dashboard", {
        url : "/dashboard",
        views : {
            "content" : {
                templateUrl : "app/modules/dashboard/dashboard.html",
                controller : "dashboardController"
            },
            "settings" : {
                templateUrl : "app/templates/settings.html"
            },
            "menu": {
                templateUrl: "app/templates/menu.html"
            }
        }
    });
    $stateProvider.state("app.demo", {
        url : "/demo",
        views : {
            "content" : {
                templateUrl : "app/modules/demo/demo.html",
                controller : "demoController"
            }
        }
    });
```

And theme.html looks like this :

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">

    <ion-side-menu-content drag-content="true">

        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable nav-title-slide-ios7 two-side" align-title="center">

            <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear inverse">
                <i class="icon ion-ios7-arrow-back">
                </i>&lt; Back
            </ion-nav-back-button>

            <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
                <button menu-toggle="left" id="menuBtn" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon inverse"></button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>

            <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
                <button menu-toggle="right" id="settingsBtn" class="button button-icon icon ion-gear-b inverse"></button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>
        </ion-nav-bar>

        <ion-nav-view name="content">
        </ion-nav-view>

    </ion-side-menu-content>

    <ion-side-menu side="left">
        <ion-nav-view name="menu" animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-side-menu>

    <ion-side-menu side="right">
        <ion-nav-view name="settings" animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-side-menu>

</ion-side-menus>
```

> Issue is when I am going from app.dashboard to app.demo first time,
>   demoController is called. Then I go back to app.dashboard. And when
>   again going to app.demo state any number of times, demoController is
>   never called. app.demo view is cached. I don't know why.

*In addition, I don't want to put cache-view=false or cache false in routing config because that disables the caching of that page totally(Forward & Backward). I want to reload page when I go in forward direction like app.dashboard to app.demo but not to reload page when I go in backward direction like app.demochild(For example) -> app.demo.*

**If I delete both ion-side-menu tag from my theme.html, the issue gets resolved, demoController is called every time when going in forward direction, But I want both ion-side-menu to be present in my theme.html**

I have even disabled the forward caching.

```
 $ionicConfigProvider.views.forwardCache(false);
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic broadcast multiple things while changing a route, like'$ionicView.beforeEnter', '$ionicView.enter' etc.

write condition to check whether its in forward direction / backward direction and call $state.reload() accordingly in your broadcast handler

```js
$scope.$on("$ionicView.beforeEnter", function(event, data){
  if()//check for the direction backward / forward
    {
      $state.reload();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Fahad, Thank you for your response. What you mentioned will be a last option for me, to use ionic view life cycle and reloading the state if required. But It's not exactly I want. I want to understand why view 'app.demo' is being cached anyway? and when I remove both the side menu, what is happening internally and why It's not being cached.